# Issue building app after upgrading from RN 0.68 to 0.70

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, gradlew

In the process of upgrading my app from RN v0.68 to RN v0.70 , I ran the npx react-native upgrade command and then start following [this guide](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.2&to=0.70.6) to finish things up and now my builds start failing after upgrade.
This is the output of my gradlew clean and I get the same error on building app for debug.

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'E:\GitHub\app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 99

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Cannot invoke method getAbsolutePath() on null object

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
```

this is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def projectRoot = rootDir.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: ["node", "-e", "require('expo/scripts/resolveAppEntry')", projectRoot, "android"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(),
    enableHermes: true,
    cliPath: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/cli.js",
    hermesCommand: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('hermes-engine/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/%OS-BIN%/hermesc",
    composeSourceMapsPath: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/scripts/compose-source-maps.js",
]

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../react.gradle")
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds =true

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    flavorDimensions "default"
    
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        prod {
        }
        qa {
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        }
        demo{
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.employeeapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 202212301
        versionName "2022.12.30"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build",
                        "-DNODE_MODULES_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules",
                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                    // abiFilters "armeabi-v7a","x86"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)
            configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureCMakeDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword project.env.get("DEBUG_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias project.env.get("DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword project.env.get("DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('unipe.keystore')
            storePassword project.env.get("STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias project.env.get("KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword project.env.get("KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}
["pickFirsts", "excludes", "merges", "doNotStrip"].each { prop ->
    def options = (findProperty("android.packagingOptions.$prop") ?: "").split(",");
    for (i in 0..<options.size()) options[i] = options[i].trim();
    options -= ""

    if (options.length > 0) {
        println "android.packagingOptions.$prop += $options ($options.length)"
        options.each {
            android.packagingOptions[prop] += it
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.1.0'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-distribute:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0-alpha01'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
       implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
            exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
        }
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
                    .because("On New Architecture we're building Hermes from source")
        }
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

Was upgrading from RN v0.68 to RN v0.70 and had to make some manual code changes for the update , post update the app fails to build. Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73943777/a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app-cannot-invoke-method-getabsolute) to no avail.